# MIPS how to allocate array space with a few predefined numbers within?

Tags: arrays, memory, mips, allocation

Is it possible to pre-load numbers into a memory array, without pre-loading all of them?

For example, say I want an array with 5 numbers, but I only know the first number, and not the last 4.

```
Array: .space 20
```

The above line would just allocate space for 5 numbers (each 4 bytes long). I want something more along the lines of:

```
Array: .word 7, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

I'd like to do a combination of these, where I can pre-define the space for an array, pre-define the first number in the array, but NOT pre-define the last four 0s in the array.

Answer (score 2):

> The above line would just allocate space for 5 numbers (each 4 bytes long). I want something more along the lines of: `Array: .word 7, 0, 0, 0, 0`

You can achieve that with:

```
Array: .word 7
       .space 16
```